# Share files between users

Tags: php, html

I have created an application which is based on PHP MySQL and I'm using XAMP server. Currently, I have created registration and login functionality for users and users can upload and download their own files. All the files are stored in the uploads/ folder. I have stored these files using the user's id in another table. so one table is for storing users details and another table for storing user's files according to their id. Now, I want to create functionality which allows a user to share the file to another user.

When I fetch all the files a user has uploaded, I tried to show a button next to the file that says "share", that button sends the users filename but I am not sure how will I pass the other user's id with whom I want to share the file and with that being passed, how can I share the file to the selected user.
below is the code for displaying the logged in users file and the link through which share can be implemented.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
        $filename = $row['file'];
        $filetype = $row['type'];
        $filesize = $row['size'];
        echo "
        <tr>
        <td>$filename</td>
        <td>$filetype</td>
        <td>$filesize KB</td>
        <td><a href='uploads/$filename' target='_blank'> Download file </br></td>
        <td><a href='delete.php?del=$filename' class='link'>Delete</td> 
        <td> <a href='shareFile.php?share=$filename' class='shareFile'>Share File </td>
        </tr>";



    }

}
else {
    echo "<p>NO FILES UPLOADED YET</p>";
}
```

below is the table for users:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Files that a user uplaods is stored in the user_files according the user's id. Below is the table for user_files table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_files` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `file` longtext NOT NULL,
  `uploaded_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `size` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this case I may suggest that you add another field (column) to the user files table. This field may be called 'shared_users_id' and should hold a comma separated lists of ids of the shared users. For Ex.

Table: user_files

```
---------------------------------------
id | user_id | file | shared_users_id |
---------------------------------------
1  |1        |sample.jpg|2,3,4        |
---------------------------------------
```

**Update 1:**

When the **share button** is clicked, you can first make an AJAX request that list names of users available to be *shared*

```php
<?php
   // Select all from users
   if(mysqli_num_rows($query) {
      echo '<ul>';
      while($users_lists = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
         echo '<li data-id="'.$users_lists['id'].'">'.$users_lists['name'].'</li>';
      }
      echo '</ul>';
   }
```

each list should carry the ids of the shares, so when the sharer clicks on any user, make another `POST` request (maybe with AJAX) that carries the ID of the shared user, then retrieve this ID from the `$_POST` handle block and execute the following action. For Ex we first assume that you have retrieved the lists of users when the sharer clicks the **Share button**.

```js
// jQuery
$("#ajaxUserLists li").click(function(e) {
let user_id = $(this).data('id');
$.post( "handle-share.php", {user_id: user_id});
});
```

```html
<ul id="ajaxUserLists">
<li data-id="1">Vishal Limbachiya</li>
<li data-id="2">Erisan Olasheni</li>
<li data-id="3"></li>
</ul>
```

And so to get the list of users of which a file is shared, you can call on the PHP `explode` function to turn lists to array, to add a new user, you can do `array-push`, to delete a shared user, you can do `unset`, then convert back to comma separated string with the `implode` function and **update** the database.

**In the code: handle-share.php**

```php
<?php
    // Check if the AJAX request has been made
    if (isset($_POST['user_id']) {
       // request made
    // assuming that you retrieved the shared users list string into 
    // $shared_users_id variable
    $shared_users_id = $row['shared_users_id'];

    // Firstly turn if to array
    $shared_users = explode(",",trim($shared_users_id));

    // To add shared users
    $new_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $shared_users[] = $new_id;

    // To remove a shared_user
    $user_id_to_remove = $_POST['user_id'];
    unset($shared_users[$user_id_to_remove]);

    //Convert back to comma separated string and
    // save to database

    $shared_users_id = implode(",",$shared_users);

    // Update the database table
    ...
}

?>
```

**Update 2:**

**Find shared items for the current User**

To inform a user that a file has been shared with him, it would have been so better to create a new table which has relationship with `user_files` table, the created tab stores details whenever a file is shared to a user, it records the `name, time_shared, sharer_id, shared_user_id, is_seen` the `is_seen` field tells whether the **shared user** has already seen the shared file or not (in order to create a **file share** notification system). But for the purpose of our table structure, You can run a PHP query like:

```php
...
$current_user_id = 4;
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "select user_id, file from user_files where find_in_set($current_user_id,shared_users_id) <> 0");

// number of shared files
$number_of_shared_files = mysqli_num_rows($query);
// list all shared items and sharer_id
while($results = mysqli_fecth_assoc($query) {
      echo $results['file'].' '.$results['user_id'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Hey Erisan, how can I add new users id through the web interface? when the user is logged in, he should be seeing a button that says 'Share'. When he clicks on that button it should ask him with whom he wants to share the file(like a textbox) when he enters the name, then that other username's id should be stored in shared_users_id, how can I implement that? That's my question.

Comment: Hey @ErisanOlasheni, I have implemented the "show list of user" functionality and now the user can see a list of users through dropdown and when he selects the user to share with, I'll implement the php code that you suggested. But, how will I display the other user that a file has been shared with him? Because in the database, the shared_users_id has multiple ids seperated with commas. we cannot query multiple ids which are seperated by commas right?

Comment: @VishalLimbachiya we can please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

First i don't see that in user_files table you have the reference who user own the file.

After adding that column, I would suggest to create a new table, who will have the info who fileId is shared with who User. The complete database should look like:

Users:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

User files:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_files` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `file` longtext NOT NULL,
  `uploaded_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `size` int(11) NOT NULL.
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Shared with:

```
CREATE TABLE `shared_files` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `file_id` int(11) NOT_NULL REFERENCES user_files(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
  `with_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Hey Bojmaliev, I didn't want to show username in both the tables, so I matched users id and stored the id in user_files which tells me which user uploaded the file according to their id. So id in user and id in user_files are same.

Comment: If you use the same id in user_files and users, then your user wont have the option to upload more then 1 files except you are using a composite primary key which makes more then one column to be a primary key.

Comment: I don't have any primary key, so I can have a user upload multiple files and id can be same as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a common table which contains userids with shared file

```
CREATE TABLE shared_files (
   id int(11) NOT NULL,
   file_id int(11) NOT_NULL REFERENCES user_files(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
   with_user_id int(11) NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

With the share button, you have to select a user from drop-down.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
        $filename = $row['file'];
        $filetype = $row['type'];
        $filesize = $row['size'];
        echo "
        <tr>
        <td>$filename</td>
        <td>$filetype</td>
        <td>$filesize KB</td>
        <td><a href='uploads/$filename' target='_blank'> Download file </br></td>
        <td><a href='delete.php?del=$filename' class='link'>Delete</td>
        <td><select id='userSelectId'>".
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($users)){
          "<option value='".$users['id']."'>".$users['username']."</option>"
        }
        ."</select></td>
        <td> <a href='shareFile.php?share=$filename&userId=$('#userSelectId option:selected').val()' class='shareFile'>Share File </td>
        </tr>";
    }
```

***I think, this will give your basic idea, how to send UserId to database on click share link***

Comment: The userId is not being passed through that href link it does not read from the dropdown selected. And how can I process that to share file between those 2 users in the shareFile.php? That was my main question.